# redirect after form submit using php not working

Tags: php, forms, redirect, post, header

Hi I'm creating a login/registration and the database communication is fine already (data get's stored and loaded as intended). 
I used Adobe Muse to design the login page and used the form widget to create inputs. On the page "login.html" i have the following form:

```
<form class="form-grp clearfix mse_pre_init" id="widgetu63897" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="login_script.php">

  <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu63910" data-required="true"><!-- none box -->
     <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv rounded-corners clearfix grpelem" id="u63913-4"><!-- content --><input class="wrapped-input" type="email" spellcheck="false" id="widgetu63910_input" name="email" tabindex="1"/><label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt" id="widgetu63910_prompt" for="widgetu63910_input"><span class="actAsPara">E-Mail or username</span></label></span>
  </div>

  <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu63900" data-required="true" data-type="email"><!-- none box -->
    <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv rounded-corners clearfix grpelem" id="u63901-4"><!-- content --><input class="wrapped-input" type="password" spellcheck="false" id="widgetu63900_input" name="password" tabindex="2"/><label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt" id="widgetu63900_prompt" for="widgetu63900_input"><span class="actAsPara">Password</span></label></span>
  </div>

  <button class="submit-btn NoWrap rounded-corners clearfix grpelem" id="u63909-4" data-muse-uid="U63909" data-muse-type="txt_frame" type="submit" value="Login" tabindex="3"><!-- content -->
   <div style="margin-top:-12px;height:12px;">
    <p>Login</p>
   </div>
  </button>    
</form>
```

So to test if the login_script.php gets executed I let it send an email to myself which worked. However, if I want to redirect from login_script.php it doesn't work. I have deleted all the code from login_script.php exept for the redirections.

I've tried using

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 'index.html';
}
?>
```

As well as

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
   header('location:index.html');
}
?>
```

I have no clue what else I could try to fix this issue

Comment: We need to know where abouts in your script you ran the `header()` function. Remember that `header()` send a header to the browser, and ALL headers must be sent BEFORE anything else is sent to the browser or it will be ignored. So if your `header('location:index.html');` is coded after yoru HTML it wont do anything

Comment: You also may need to change `header('location:index.html');` to `header('Location: index.html');` Note the uppercase `L` in location

Comment: For your first method, your `echo` is wrong!  change it to `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 'index.html';</script>"`

Comment: Hmm ... can you dump the content of $_SERVER variable.        
It may be that for some reason the condition `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` is not true.  
  You can also [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12754459)

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your solutionsIt seems that the code generated by Adobe Muse `<script type="text/javascript">
 if(typeof Muse != "undefined") window.Muse = {}; 
</script>` is causing the problem. everything works as it should after I removed it. However the design gets all messed up when removing it (e.g. the grayed out hints in the input fields don't disappear anymore and the form is off center) I am new to Javascript so if anyone has an idea how to fix this I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try this if the problem still persists kindly comment

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
   header('Location:http://google.co.in');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function redirect($url)
{
    if (strpos($url, '://') === false)
    {
        // Make URL absolute
        $url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $url;
    }

    if (headers_sent())
    {
        // Send the redirect statement via JavaScript.
        echo "<script>window.location.replace(\"$url\");</script>\n";
    }
    else
    {
        // Use the more efficient HTTP header for redirection.
        header('Location: ' . $url);
    }

    exit;
}

redirect('index.php');
```

See also

- [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)
- [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)
- [$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754388/serverrequest-method-does-not-exist)

Answer (score -1):

Try to echo in

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
```

and if it works then Try this.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```